# Вывод Title страницы не на всех страницах

Tags: wordpress

Хочу сделать вывод title страницы не на всех страницах, например на нужных страницах, чтобы он не выводился. Как это можно реализовать?
Использовал функцию `wp_get_document_title()` или `the_title()`, но как сделать выборку не пойму

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, натолкнули на мысль. Воспользовался функцией is_page():

```
<?php if (!is_page( array(66, 124) )) {the_title();}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

в wordpress-е есть стандартные функции для таких задач, например is_single() или is_category() или другие. Почитай [тут](http://wp-kama.ru/function/is_single), [тут](http://wp-kama.ru/function/is_category). На [этом сайте](http://wp-kama.ru/) есть вся информация про wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант так же сделать для каждой страницы/статьи дополнительное поле-галочку - выводить или не выводить. Если интересно напишу подробнее.